# Pass dictionary from view to controller after form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, routevalues

Razor view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Move", "Details", new { dict= dictionary}, FormMethod.Post)) {
    //table with info and submit button
    //dictionary => is a dictionary of type <Sales_Order_Collected, string>
}
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Move(Dictionary<Sales_Order_Collected, string> dict) {
    return "";
}
```

Is there a way to pass the model dictionary to the controller? Because my parameter is always null.

Answer (score 6):

you can not pass dictionary through route values. You can do something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Move", "Details", null, FormMethod.Post)) {
    <input type="text" name="[0].Key" value="first key"/>
    <input type="text" name="[0].Value" value="first value"/>

    <input type="text" name="[1].Key" value="second key"/>
    <input type="text" name="[1].Value" value="second value"/>
}
```

This will post Dictionary. The idea for complex objects is the same

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Html helper for any dictionary:

```
public static IHtmlString DictionaryFor<TModel, TKey, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, IDictionary<TKey, TValue>>> expression)
{
    ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

    IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary = (IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)metaData.Model;

    StringBuilder resultSB = new StringBuilder();

    int i = 0;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in dictionary)
    {
        MvcHtmlString hiddenKey = htmlHelper.Hidden($"{metaData.PropertyName}[{i}].Key", kvp.Key.ToString());
        MvcHtmlString hiddenValue = htmlHelper.Hidden($"{metaData.PropertyName}[{i}].Value", kvp.Value.ToString());

        resultSB.Append(hiddenKey.ToHtmlString());
        resultSB.Append(hiddenValue.ToHtmlString());

        i++;
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(resultSB.ToString());
}
```

Call it in a View like this:

```
@Html.DictionaryFor(model => model.AnyDictionary)
```